# License plate character segmentation python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation

I want to isolate every character in the following image:
[image]

and it should create a rectangular bounding box around each character. My code is creating a circular bounding box. I need to supply these isolated character images to my trained model to predict the character. I haven't done image processing before which leads me to asking such a question.

This is the code I'm using:

```
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np;

from PIL import Image
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10;
params.maxThreshold = 200;

#Filter by Color

params.filterByColor=False
params.blobColor=255

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = False
params.minArea = 50

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = False
params.minCircularity = 0.0785
#
# # Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.minConvexity = 0.87
#
# # Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = False
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01
# Read image
    im = cv2.imread("C:\\xx\\testimages\\bw_plate.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.threshold(im,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,im)


# Set up the detector with default parameters.
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)


# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                                      cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My output with the following code is: 
[image]

Why is it not detecting 0 and 2 properly? Also how can I create separate jpeg files for every isolated character?

The C++ implementation of my project uses [CblobResult](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/object-detection-using-the-opencv-cvblobslib-libraries/) class which did the segmentation. Is there any equivalent library in python?

This is what the final output must look like for every character after segmentation:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After removing background noises you can input image like this:

[image]

Then you can get what you want using following code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('test4.jpg', 0)
cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU,img)
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
cv2.imshow("contours", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
d=0
for ctr in contours:
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    # Getting ROI
    roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    cv2.imshow('character: %d'%d,roi)
    cv2.imwrite('character_%d.png'%d, roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    d+=1
```

Comment: Hi, could you also add the code you wrote for removing the background noises? The code for segmentation works perfectly.

Comment: Since this question is about segmenting I did removing noises manually.

Comment: Hi, i tried using your code but I kept getting errors for the cv2.findContours line as it only returns two values. Is there a way to get around this?