# Pre Trained LeNet Model for License plate Recognition

Tags: tensorflow, keras, ocr, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I have implemented a form of the LeNet model via **tensorflow and python** for a **Car number plate recognition system**. My model was trained solely on my train data and tested on the test data. **My dataset contains segmented images wherein every image has only one character in them.** This is what my [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713023/license-plate-character-segmentation-python-opencv) looks like. My created model does not perform very well, so I'm now looking for models which I can use via Transfer Learning. Since most models, are already trained on a humongous dataset, I looked over a few like AlexNet, ResNet, GoogLeNet and Inception v2. Most of these models have not been trained on the type of data that I want which would be, **Letters and digits.**

**Question:** Should I still go forward with one of these models and train them on my dataset or are there any better models which would help ? For such models would keras be a better option since it is more high level than Tensorflow?

**Question:** I'd prefer to work with the LeNet model itself since training the other models would definitely take a long time due to the insufficient specs of my laptop. So is there any implementation of the model which uses machine printed character images to train the model which I could use to then train the final layers of the model on my data?

Answer (score 0):

to get good results you should use a model explicitly designed for text recognition. 
First, (roughly) crop the input image to the region around the text.
Then, feed the image of the text into a neural network (NN) to detect the text.
A typical NN for text recognition extracts relevant features (with convolutional NN), propagates those features through the image (with recurrent NN) and finally predicts a character score for each position in the image.
Usually, those networks are trained with the CTC loss.

As a starting point I would suggest looking at the CRNN implementation (they also provide a pre-trained model) [1] and the corresponding paper [2]. There is, as far as I remember, also a TensorFlow implementation on github.
You can use any framework (e.g TensorFlow or CNTK or ...) you like as long as it features convolutional and recurrent NN and the CTC loss.
I once attended a presentation about CNTK where they claimed that they have a very fast implementation of recurrent NN - so maybe CNTK would be a good choice for your slow computer?

[1] CRNN implementation: https://github.com/bgshih/crnn

[2] Shi - An End-to-End Trainable Neural Network for Image-based Sequence Recognition and Its Application to Scene Text Recognition

Comment: Hi, I'm using python. Is there any python implementation of CRNN? My dataset contains segmented images wherein every image has only one character in them. Are you talking about the attention ocr? (tensorflow implementation?) I don't think I require RNNs at the moment. I'm quite confused as to how to proceed.

Comment: You have to rework your question and add some more information about the data. I thought you want to detect the text on license plates, however, what you really want is just some digit-classifer extended by some more classes for whatever chars you need.

Comment: So my model is a license plate text recognizer which gives the text stored in that plate. 
I have edited this question.
Also I've added a link to another question of mine which shows the kind of data I am using. I'll be feeding in the segmented character images to my model as input.  Let me know if there is any more data required?

Comment: you do it in two steps: 1. segmentation, 2. char classification. Usually its a good idea to avoid segmentation (as its error-prone) and instead train one single NN which directly detects the complete text from the plates. Your segmentation code relies on nearly noise-free images, which will seldom be the case in real life. CRNN, on the other hand, does not need to segment the characters, which is a great benefit. So I would at least give it a try, search github for "CRNN TensorFlow" and train it on your data.