# how to extract text from image after applying contouring

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to get letters from license plate image, for that I took an image and changed it to gray then applied threshold to it. Then using contours I cropped image having only license plate.I used python for this

code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2
import imutils

img = "d1.jpg"
# load the image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(T, threshInv) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("Threshold", threshInv)

#masking
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

# find all contours in the image and draw ALL contours on the image
cnts=cv2.findContours(threshInv.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
clone = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(clone, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
print("Found {} contours".format(len(cnts)))

for cnt in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    crop = image[y:(y+h),x:(x+w)]
    if(w>300 and h>100 and w<700 and h<500):
        print("detected")
        cv2.imshow('plate',crop)
        cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), 255, -1)
        break
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(clone, clone, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("Mask Applied to Image", masked)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[contouring applied image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5AHp.png)
can anyone help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50713277/5430055

Comment: I want to extract text from image in letters and then I should able to store the number. Thank you

Comment: Yes you can do so using the example I have given @Divyareddy

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do: optical character recognition? If yes you might try Tesseract: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/

Answer (score 0):

The following GitHub link might help you to understand the text extraction from the image

https://github.com/anuj-badhwar/Indian-Number-Plate-Recognition-System

It basically uses pytesseract library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) it helped me alot